# Как поочередно сложить значения двух массивов?

Tags: php, javascript, циклы

В чем сабж. Есть два больших массива вида:

```
$array1 = array (собака, кошка, птица);
$array2 = array (Москва, Питер, Новосиб, Хабаровск);
```

Кол-во значений в массиве мы не знаем заранее ни в первом массиве, ни во втором.

Нужно брать одно значение из первого массива складывать со всеми значениями второго. Потом второе значение из первого массива складываем со всем значениями второго массива и т.д.

Просто вывести "собака москва" , "кошка Питер" у меня получается А чтобы было вот так:

```
Собака Москва
Собака Питер
Собака Новосиб
Собака Хабаровск
...

Птица Хабаровск
```

У меня не выходит. Добрые люди подскажите, как правильно написать цикл и как сложить. Либо на php либо на js. Без разницы.

Comment: Вам нужен цикл в цикле. Где Ваш код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки у строковых значений всё же рекомендуется ставить.

```php
$array1 = ['собака','кошка','птица'];
$array2 = ['Москва','Питер','Новосиб','Хабаровск'];

foreach($array1 as $pet) {
    foreach($array2 as $city) {
        echo "$pet $city<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Кавычки это понятно, это я просто для примера писал. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr1 = ['собака', 'кошка', 'птица'],
  arr2 = ['Москва', 'Питер', 'Новосиб', 'Хабаровск'],
  arr3 = [];
arr1.forEach(function(req) {
  arr2.forEach(function(req2) {
    arr3[arr3.length] = req + ' ' + req2;
  });
});
console.log(arr3);
```